# setting viewbox coordinates to extents of svg drawing

Tags: svg, zooming, limits, viewbox

I have a set of dynamically created svg objects. Some of them have rather complicated transformations applied to. I mean this is meaningless that I want to calculate maximum and minimums of X & Y of these objects. I want viewbox (or any similar tag that may be useful) to show all these objects without engaging me in calculating extents of drawing objects.

Could you please help?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve - your question perhaps needs more detail. Are you rendering using a browser? What are you using to dynamically create svg elements?

Comment: also, what language are you using?

Comment: I'm using browser to show svg.Please take a look at code:

<svg id="SVG1" width="500" height="500" viewBox="0 -100 200 200">
<g id="G2">
<line x1="0" y1="0" x2="100" y2="100" stroke="blue"/>
<line x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="100" stroke="blue"/>
<line x1="0" y1="0" x2="100" y2="0" stroke="blue"/>
<line x1="0" y1="0" x2="100" y2="-100" stroke="blue"/>
</g>
</svg>

this works fine. But after removing viewbox, negative parts are not shown.
This time I knew that  viewBox="0 -100 200 200" will show all drawing objects. but what to do when I can't get to know this. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use getBBox() on the path element to get the extents of your drawing.

```
var clientrect = path.getBBox();
var viewBox = clientrect.x+' '+clientrect.y+' '+clientrect.width+' '+clientrect.height;
```

You can then set the viewbox to these co-ordinates.

n.b. i think you can change the viewbox of an svg after it's rendered so you may have to re-render the svg.